# Writing different message in different TextAreas with TextWebsocketFrame in netty

Tags: java, javascript, netty

For writing to a socket I am using.
**channels.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(String msg));**
and in my webpage (that is displayed to the client) I obtain the data from the event(*event.data*) and display it in the text area(say T1).
but i have 2 text area's (say T1 and T2) and in both of them I want to display different data.I cant figure out a way to do this. So if i could get some implementation or some way to get the desired functionality.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to encode in the WebSocketFrame some "marker" that can be used to detect to which frame the text goes. For example you could use Json or something like this

Comment: By setting some flag in json and retrieving that flag value from json in javascripts and then on the basis of that flag value i should decide in which text area "event.data" should be called(to fetch data from websocket),Is this what you meant?